# Launching a shortcut with an Intent only in Chrome and removing the status bar

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, android-intent, android-activity

I have used this site: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/fullscreen/ to get a full screen web page. But this gives me a shortcut icon on the home page.

Is there anyway with an Intent to load the shortcut in Chrome only and also remove the status bar?

Thanks,

Edit:

What I mean is can I load a webpage in Chrome using an Intent such as:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
        browserIntent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
        startActivity(browserIntent);
```

And have this load full screen without the status bar, to make use of the whole screen.  I can hide this loading a native app in the manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

But this does not have any effect on an Intent, how would I do this using an Intent?

Comment: Once you pass control to another app through an intent, it's up to the authors of that app to do what they will with the intent you pass it.  Have you considered using a webview and displaying it yourself?

Comment: @BrianHibbert I have put into the Web App HTML the meta tag <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">  But still cannot get it to load full screen as I need to save it as a shortcut and cannot get this to load with an intent. At the moment I cannot use a WebView as I need this to load with Google Chrome.